# OpenShift Web root directory

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have an openshift node.js + Mongodb server set up. I am SFTP in from sublime text. Where is the root web directory? I see copies of the *index.html* file everywhere but changing them does nothing. I have read other posts about it being in `app-root/data/site`, but I do not have a *sites* folder.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to find the webroot of your application running its `app-root/runtime/repo`. However, I would strongly suggest you make changes through Git if you're altering code. If your uploading things like pictures or other data, you'll want to store them in your `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` which is located at `/app-root/data/`

Comment: Hi. I uploaded some photos with git client. There are stored in runtime/repo. What should ho in $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR. Do you have an exemple ? Do you mean for storing file with IO access ?

Comment: I having some json file with my data to show. I'm using harpjs to render it as a static web. Do you think i should move my json data to $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR ?